# How to receive/send vm:// mule messages from a spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, mule, mule-component

I want to instantiate a bean and send/receive vm:// messages to/from flows. I followed [this](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/sending-and-receiving-mule-events-in-spring) but the overridden methods do not get any messages. Do I need to instantiate a VM connector and pass its reference to the bean that implements MuleSubscriptionEventListener first?

Answer (score 2):

VM are perfectly valid in many cases, specially in Mule EE with the HA cluster.

If what you need is to send to vm from a spring referenced java component you have two options to consider:

- Using a [MuleClient](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.5/using-the-mule-client) with the MuleContext (obtained either with
  [MuleContextAware](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/context/MuleContextAware.html), from a [Message](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/MuleMessage.html) or injected).
- Or using
  [Component Bindings](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/component-bindings).

Comment: Can you add some code to demonstrate the use of MuleClient or provide more detail?

Comment: See the below code on how to use the mule client in Spring referenced java class to trigger VM : @Override 
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception { 
MuleContext context=eventContext.getMuleContext(); 
MuleClient client=(MuleClient) context.getClient(); 
eventContext.getMessage().setPayload("Congrates, mule client class"); 
MuleMessage message=client.send("vm://testVmpath",(MuleMessage) eventContext.getMessage());

Comment: Victor is right in saying the the flow will jump from one node to another node in the cluster if you model VM-Endpoints into the flow. The issue is just: It will not improve your performance by doing that! It will simply jump from one node to another. It can make reading the logs quite difficult if your flow jumps over multiple nodes for the processing of a single execution. If you want to control your cluster's load you should use some proxy that balances the nodes. Flow references offer similar "Processing strategies" like VM-Endpoints (synchronous, As-sync, multi threading et cetera)

Comment: Indeed. HA stands for High Availability rather than High Performance.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. It should work for sending, but how do I subscribe to receive VM messages?

Comment: There is no easy way to easily receive from within Java. You can of course, but you are not meant to use internal mechanisms. However, it should be simple to receive in a flow and delegate to a Java component. However, before bypassing Mule, think twice if you are doing the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Generally Mule encourages developers to not use vm-endpoints anymore, see for example the [Mule VM docs](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/vm-transport-reference)

Quote:

> The VM transport has often been used to implement complex integrations
>   made up of multiple applications. Improvements in Mule 3 obviate the
>   need for VM in many cases. You can use Flow References to directly
>   reference one flow from another without a transport in the middle.

I would really consider Flow References, they are much better. For VM-Endpoints Mule creates a entire different thing (passing variables around in the header of the message payload) et cetera.

VM Endpoints only make sense if you want to make certain sub-flows possible to call from external, like for example from a Unit-Test.

I think the implementation described in the docs you linked are quite complicated. Why are you not simply putting a Java-Component into the Mule flow that links to Spring bean? That way you can fully control the invocation from Mule to Spring. It can be either a Java Transformer or a Java Component. I think so far Java Component sounds more like what you need:

See: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/using-spring-beans-as-flow-components

Comment: My goal is to have a reusable component I can just plug in and configure other flows to send messages to it or receive them. I considered flow references, VM however fit my case better as having different kinds of queues will help me to differentiate between the messages and take some specific action depending on what queue the message is received. If I were to use flow references I would have to set some message properties and this would make the flows messy.